# Minimum cost path for N*N matrix in ϴ(N^2) time

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time-complexity

I am provided with an N*N matrix of towns, and each town has a respective widget price (a weight).

I am tasked with finding the cheapest cost to acquire a widget for every town, using the following equation:

```
Cost for target town : (Target Town Cost) + (Rectilinear distance away from base town)
Cheapest Total Cost for base town = min(costs calculated for all target towns)
```

The simple solution is ϴ(N<sup>4</sup>), where we go through all N<sup>2</sup> base towns, and calculate the cost for all N<sup>2</sup> targets and the answer is the minimum.

I need to find a solution in ϴ(N<sup>2</sup>). I know there is a dynamic programming solution but we have not covered that yet so I am trying to find an alternative.

Solutions I have tried so far:

1. Calculating the cost for middle row and column, then recursively calculating the costs for the middle row and column for every sub-grid. This would however be ϴ(log(N<sup>2</sup>)N<sup>2</sup>), since calculating the mininum for the initial row and column would be ϴ((number of base towns) * (checking all target towns)) = ϴ(log(N<sup>2</sup>)N<sup>2</sup>)
2. Creating a min-heap based on the smallest town, but this would still take ϴ(N<sup>2</sup>log(N)) due to building the heap.

The current attempt I am trying seems to be leading me in the right direction. We can start out by

1. Finding the minimum cost town of the whole grid, and we know it is its own minimum cost town. That will take N<sup>2</sup>
2. Take the surrounding towns. Their minimum cost will either be themselves, or the global minimum.
3. We recurs onto the surrounding towns again, and here I don't know what to do. I am looking for a property of the already calculated towns that I could take advantage of in order to calculate each current surrounding town in constant time.

Is there something to this or should I consider some other method?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure about "Cost for target town : (Target Town Cost) + (Rectilinear distance away from base town)"? In that case the answer is trivial: select a town as close as possible to the center of the grid. Since the sum of the absolute cost of all towns can be split up into the sum of the cost of all towns and the sum of all rectilinear distances to the base town. First sum is fixed, second sum can  be maximized by selecting a town as central as possible

Comment: @Paul, just curious, sounds like your method also works for Euclidean distance? Is there any more general rule such that if the rule is satisfied then your method will work? like if Cost for target town = (Target Town Cost) + d(base, target) for any metric d?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic depends upon the metric. This approach will work for any metric that is proportional (in the sense of order-preserving, like `eud(a, b) < eud(c, d) => d(a, b) < d(c, d)`) to the euclidean metric, since in that case the question reduces to "find the barycenter of a square of size `N x N`". Though I guess there's a mistake in the question, as this wouldn't require any coding at all.

Comment: @Paul I am not convinced that the answer is always the center of the grid, because then if you continually add rows and columns to the north east of the grid, the answer this calculates shifts to the north east. I think the answer for minimising the sum of absolute differences in X and Y directions is the median, because if you move away from the median there will eventually be more points behind you than ahead of you and the sum of distances to points behind you will increase greater than the sum of distances to points ahead of you.

Comment: @mcdowella It's a fixed grid with a symmetric distance metric. If you move the base away from the center, you'll always increase the summed-up distance. That's trivial to show. And to be honest, I don't have the slightest clue what you want to show with your proof. 1.: median of what? 2.: whats wrong about the barycenter moving north-east, if we add weight in the north-east?

Comment: @Paul I am referring to the optimality property of the median described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Optimality_property. For example, you should find that in one dimension the number that minimizes the sum of absolute differences between that number and {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} is 3, which is the median of this set of numbers.

Comment: @mcdowella I know what a median is. But the median is a metric on a certain input. Simply saying "use the median" is like saying "use a drill" without telling which wall needs a hole. If you mean the median of the coordinates: well, you've just defined the center of the matrix by statistical means, apart from that there's absolutely no difference to my approach. Or is this about the cost of each town? In that case: the target-towns can be extracted out of the total-cost metric, since they're a constant factor that is being added.